# Windows 7 SP1 stuck on updating, Windows 10 installer does the same

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

So for some unknown reason, Windows refuses to load updates, and refuses to give an error when no internet is connected. Running the Windows update trouble shooter states that there is an error, but it is not fixed.

> 0x80070057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have facing same problem few weeks ago with windows 7 ultimate sp1, after i run microsoft update fix it and i run windows update again the error code appear, i resolved the problem by renaming C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder with SoftwareDistribution_old, after that restart the PC and run update again.

When i run the update a few minutes, it looks like nothing happen, no disk activity and no upload/download activity, and windows update only show checking... for long time, when i check the CPU usage it show 49-51% used by svchost.exe for wuauserv process, i leave it just like that and do nothing until almost 2 hours and then the windows update show the available update.
After installing the important updates and check the updates again, it took only about 5-10 minutes for windows update to checking.

I just shared my experience here and what i have done cannot be used as a guide, looks like we need extra patient with windows update.